# PostgreSQL: command not found

Tags: macos, unix, postgresql

I installed PostgreSQL via MacPorts. However, going to `/opt/local/lib/postgresql84/bin` I am unable to execute any of the pg commands. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 20):

When you say "going to", it sounds like you're using the `cd` command to change to that directory. Something like:

```
$ cd /opt/local/lib/postgresql84/bin
$ psql
psql: command not found
```

Normally on Unix systems, the current directory is *not* part of your executable search path. So either explicitly execute `psql` from the current directory using `./`:

```
$ cd /opt/local/lib/postgresql84/bin
$ ./psql
```

or, add the directory to your `PATH`:

```
$ export PATH=/opt/local/lib/postgresql84/bin:$PATH
$ psql
```

Answer (score 7):

I had installed postgres (Mac,The capitan SO) with the dmg and also I got the same issue. I had to install psql through brew. Try with this :

```
brew install postgres
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

Try this command:

```
find / -name psql
```

Comment: Thanks BarsMonster.  I put the paths 
/opt/local/bin
/opt/local/sbin
/opt/local/lib/postgresql84/bin
in my ~/.bash_profile, and that fixed it.  

Still not sure why psql didn't work, when I went straight to /opt/local/lib/postgresql84/bin though...

Comment: Probably because current directory is not in your "PATH".

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
whereis psql
```